# How do I make this Modal dialog more responsive?

Tags: html, css

Unresponsive Modal Dialog, without using Media queries or JS is what the goal (was) is. Can be done - but I have since lost the code to update the question.

You can see it on this Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4qkonfLk/

Code:

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close2 {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close2:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#openModal" class="button">Other Information </a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close2">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by more responsive? Can you explain more please?

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions by removing all relevant details. If you want to indicate that @media queries are the answer, then accept roberto tomas's answer by clicking the checkmark in the margin. Or, you can post an answer of your own, if you aren't completely satisfied with his.

Comment: Okay, well I can't delete it, I want it gone off my profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify mobile-only `CSS` by using `media` queries, media queries applies `CSS` rules only in specific conditions such as a `width` range, for more see the following [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

In your case you can target mobiles width (which is usually `360px`) as the `max-width` of your media query as following:

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close2 {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close2:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .modalDialog > div {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal" class="button">Other Information </a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close2">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [@media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)  to create alternative renderings.

Like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

rynave's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) lists many good common ones; I think it is common to have 2-4 for:

- pc/tablet,  phone
- phone,  tablet,  pc
- phone,  tablet,  pc, hi res
  Or
- watch app, phone,  tablet,  pc

Not sure his iPhone one is so useful any more.

Comment: yea, I tried something like this. But, it didn't seem to work. I will try this article see what happens, but if its what I already did, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using some custom CSS classes based on the screensize (Media Queries)to use something different for smaller screens - I ended up scrapping the entire thing after though, so this question is pretty much irrelevant to anything in the community, since I couldn't delete it, I am editing my answers to help understand what I was talking about.